# Run (C#) algorithm assessment

Tags: algorithm

I have been doing programming algorithms lately, just to practice :). 
i got this question from a site. The problem is:

> Write a function that finds the zero-based index of the longest run in a string. A run is a consecutive sequence of the same character. If there is more than one run with the same length, return the index of the first one.

For example, IndexOfLongestRun("abbcccddddcccbba") should return 6 as the longest run is dddd and it first appears on index 6.

So what i came up is this :

```
public static int IndexOfLongestRun(string str)
    {
        string retval = string.Empty;
        string firstOccurence = string.Empty;
        string maxOccurence = string.Empty;
        string val1 = string.Empty;
        string val2 = string.Empty;
        int counter = 1;
        int occurenceCounter = 1;
        int maxOccur = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            val1 = str[i].ToString();
            if (i < str.Length - 1)
            {
                val2 = str[i + 1].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                val2 = str[i].ToString();
            }

            if (val1 == val2)
            {
                firstOccurence = val1;
                occurenceCounter = occurenceCounter + counter;

                if (occurenceCounter > counter && occurenceCounter > maxOccur)
                {
                    maxOccur = occurenceCounter;
                    maxOccurence = firstOccurence;
                }
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                occurenceCounter = 1;
            }
        }
        return str.IndexOf(maxOccurence, 0);
    }
```

This past the me on the main purpose of the test. however it fails me on performance benchmark. Could anyone shed some light on how this code of mine can be optimized? Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? You are traversing the string once, which is required in any case.

Comment: The problem is that the test case appears to have a better version of my code, to be precised more optimize.

Comment: I am not sure if you need to check every next character once you already found a run of length N. Since if character [i] and [i+N] are different, then it is obvious, that there is no run of greater length between these two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize it in a few ways:

- Firstly, `occurenceCounter > counter` condition in `if` is redundant.
- Also, don't use `str.IndexOf()`. Instead, try to store index in a variable as soon as its `occurrenceCounter` gets greater than `maxOccur`. That should be easy. (Hint: You know current index and count)

Other than that, I don't see if the code can be optimized. Also, I'm not too  familiar with C#, so, I don't know if you have a `char` type there (must be, surely). If you have to compare a single character, I'd advice not using `strings` to compare. (Something like `toChar` should be faster than `toString`).

Also, I don't think your code will pass all test cases. Check on: `kaaabbb`. Your code would return 4 (I think) (Correct o/p is 1).

For that, loop until `string.length - 2` (not `string.length - 1`, as you are doing) and remove `if` condition on assignment of `val2`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use transformation .ToString? It takes time. I suspect that C# has char type for string elements. And you'd better to work with indexes, not with run-strings. Pseudocode:

```
MaxLen = 0
MaxIndex = 0
StartIndex = 0
StartChar = s[0]
for i = 1 to s.Length - 1 do
    if s[i] != StartChar then 
         Len = i - StartIndex
         if MaxLen < Len then
             MaxLen = Len
             MaxIndex = StartIndex 
         StartIndex = i
         StartChar = s[i]
Len = s.Length - StartIndex
     if MaxLen < Len then
           MaxLen = Len
           MaxIndex = StartIndex
```